# To run a .sql -file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1146

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146470/to-read-sos-data-dump-effectively).

I run unsuccessfully

```
sudo mysql 
\. /users/cs/SO_db/posts.sql
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'personal.posts' doesn't exist
```

[MySQL's manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-server.html) says

> A five-character SQLSTATE value
>   ('42S02'). The values are specified by
>   ANSI SQL and ODBC and are more
>   standardized. Not all MySQL error
>   numbers are mapped to SQLSTATE error
>   codes. The value 'HY000'  (general
>   error) is used for unmapped errors.

and

> Error: 1146 SQLSTATE: 42S02 
>   (ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE)
>
> Message: Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist

**How can you solve the error message?**

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to put SO's user-data in .xml -form to MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the post you referenced, you NEED to create the tables first.
Peek at the XML or the SQL output on what columns you need. e.g. here is a table that can hold the output from badges.xml (I don't have the others available right now..)

```
CREATE TABLE `badges` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `UserId` int(11) not NULL,
  `Date` datetime not  NULL,
  `Name` varchar(32) not NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`),
  KEY `Date` (`Date`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`)
) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! --- You can run a SQL command according to MySQL manuals by `mysql db_name < script.sql > output.file`.

Comment: I have the table `badges` in my MyQSL database `test`. **How can you run the Python code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146470/to-read-sos-data-dump-effectively/1147259#1147259 such that it inserts the data directly to MySQL database, not to a text file as it does at the moment?**

Comment: You'd run this "python importscript.py badges.xml | mysql test"

You might need other arguments to the mysql command if you need to specify a username/password etc.

Answer (score 5):

The SQL script you have loaded makes reference to a database and/or table which does not exist in the database.

Typically one would not call the `mysql` tool with `sudo`, as the system user privileges are different from MySQL users.

To execute an SQL script through mysql I would try something like:

```
cat somefile.sql | mysql -u <mysqluser> -p <mysqldb>
```

This command would load 'somefile.sql' into `mysql` tool, connecting to a MySQL server on `localhost` as user `<mysqluser>` and selecting the database `<mysqldb>`. The `mysql` tool will prompt for `<mysqluser>`'s access password before executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually created the database 'personal' and the table 'posts'?

You might want to try something like:

```
mysql -h localhost -u <user> -p<password> -D personal < /users/cs/SO_db/posts.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posts.sql contains some statements referencing a posts table, which doesn't exist in your personal schema.

To "solve" the error, ensure the table is created!

Answer (score 0):

probably your sql file doesn't include the "create table" command.